# Empty folders with same name in /media/root/ with one usb device mounted

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I have accidentally removed my USB-stick but when I reconnected it, in my **/media/root/** directory appeared two folders of the same name, but one was empty.

```
root@linux:/media/root/$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root      4096 Feb 16 14:23 myusb
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root      4096 Feb 16 14:26 myusb1
```

How can I succesfully delete **myusb1** (the empy one) and remounting myusb without making again two folders?

**Edit:**
Resolved formatting the USB drive

Comment: Just pointing out the obvious: They do not have the same name.

Comment: Is it possible your USB drive has two partitions that are being mounted?

Comment: @DopeGhoti I don't think is a problem of the USB partition because it has never done this before, but when I accidentally ejected without unmounting it started to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. umount USB
2. eject USB
3. delete folders
4. plug USB in
5. mount USB

(I am not pro so if i am wrong just tell)

Comment: It gives me two folders again, I tried also different orders (removing the directory and then remounting the USB) but it gives me the same problem.

Comment: what does mount show ?

Comment: It said: "can't find myusb in /etc/fstab", but 'mount -o remount myusb' works.

Comment: What exactly is in your /etc/fstab and what does say whole output from mount ?

Comment: Resolved, I have formatted the USB drive